# Installation screen doesn't appear when trying to install Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, usb-installation

So, I've been trying to install Ubuntu using the guide provided on their website. I created a bootable USB using balenaEtcher, it crashed twice but I finally got it to work. I rebooted my computer (Windows 11 if that's important) and didn't get any installation screen, Windows just started as normal. So I restarted it again, and this time opened BIOS. The only option available was the ol' Windows boot. So I checked File Explorer to see if my USB somehow wasn't connected, it tells me that I have two USB-sticks connected, which is impossible since I only have one USB-port. I can't "open" either of them, format them, nor get Ubuntu to actually work...

So, what did I do wrong, and can I fix it?

Comment: Etcher crashing isn't good, it can be a symptom of a problem with the USB stick. The ISO can be corrupt. Other than that you aren't doing anything wrong. But you must learn how to boot external media, that's for sure.

Comment: Do a checksum on the .iso file. Then do a check on the usb-device you use. After making the bootdevice do a check again to make sure that it is written correctly. Then change the boot device in the UEFI ( what some people incorrectly call BIOS ) to the usb device. Try Ubuntu to see if all your harware works and if it does, install it.